# how to disable button clicks via .preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

given this tutorial https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#accessing-event-argument-in-inline-handlers

as shown below in the code, i am calling `.preventDefault` expecting cancellation of the normal behaviour of the `click` emitter. Or, in other words, i expect that once `. preventDefault` is called the button will not be any more clickable because i think, according to my understanding,
`.preventDefault` will disable the normal fucntionality of the button.

but what happens, is that the buttonn is still clickable and as if `.preventDefault` has no effect.

please let me know how to disable button clicks by using `.preventDefault` properly

**code**:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <button v-on:click="warn('msg',$event)">warn</button>     
</div>
</template>

<script> 
    import {ref} from 'vue' 

    export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      }
}
</script>
 
<script setup> 
    const warn = (msg,DOMEvent) => {
      console.log("warn:",msg," event:",DOMEvent);
      DOMEvent.preventDefault()
    }
</script>
```

Comment: preventDefault does not prevent a button from being clicked, it prevents the default *action* from taking place - if you want to prevent a button from being clicked, you could set it to be *disabled*

Comment: @JaromandaX would you please tell me what the default action of an event is?

Comment: depends on many factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preventDefault()` doesn't disable the button but prevents its default action mainly you will notice in case of `Submit` action.

To disable button on click, you need to do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <button :disabled="isDisabled" v-on:click="warn('msg',$event)">warn</button>     
</div>
</template>

<script> 
    import {ref} from 'vue' 

    export default {
      name: 'App',
      components: {
        HelloWorld
      }
}
</script>
 
<script setup> 
    const warn = (msg,DOMEvent) => {
      console.log("warn:",msg," event:",DOMEvent);
      //DOMEvent.preventDefault() //uncomment if needed
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: would you please tell me what the default action of an event is?

Comment: For links(anchors), browser will navigate to that link on click. For checkbox, on click you will see toggling of checkbox, for Submit button generally its Form Submit action.

Answer (score 1):

`event.preventDefault()` stops the current event from acting on the page.

To disable a button, you can set its [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) attribute to true.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 button.disabled = true;
 button.textContent = 'Cant touch this';
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: *stops the current event from triggering other listeners* - wrong, other listeners still get called

Answer (score 1):

preventDefault can be useful when:

- Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
- Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL

To disable your button in your case, you can use:

```
  const warn = (msg,DOMEvent) => {
  DOMEvent.srcElement.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you're using the `preventDefault` method correctly.

Read up on the [MDN Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) docs for a better take on how to use it.

First off, to disable a button, you can simply use the `disabled` attribute

```html
<button v-on:click="warn('msg',$event)" disabled>warn</button>
```

Ideally, you'll probably want to only disable it conditionally by using the `v-bind:` directive.

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="warn('msg',$event)" v-bind:disabled="isDisabled">warn</button>

        <!-- A new button to toggle disabled state -->
        <button v-on:click="toggleDisabledState">Toggle</button> 
    </div>
</template>
... 

<script setup>
    import {ref} from 'vue'

    const isDisabled = ref(false);

    const warn = (msg,DOMEvent) => {
      console.log("warn:",msg," event:",DOMEvent);
    }

    // toggle method
    const toggleDisabledState = () => {
      isDisabled.value = !isDisabled.value
    } 
</script>
```